# Disable ping in Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5

my seniors and professionals,
I know this issue is already listed on **serverfault** but I am again asking this question as none of the provided solutions worked for me. I have tried the following options.

> 1. Go to Start → Administrative Tools → Windows Firewall with Advanced Security → Inbound Rules → File and Printer Sharing (Echo Request – ICMPv4-IN) → right-click and select Enable Rule.

> 2. Number "1" solution with changed that rule's setting from "Allow" to "Block the connection".

> 3. Using **IIS** Open the application pool from IIS Manager and navigate to “Advanced Settings” from the context menu of the selected application pool. This will open the “Advanced settings” dialog window. Move to the “Process Model” section. From there select ping enables to false.

I am using Windows Server 2008 R2 and IIS  7.5.

Comment: Do you want to "disable" inbound ICMP/ping (so that youre machine will no longer answer to ping requests) or outbound ICMP/ping (so that your machine can no longer request ping from other machines) oder do you want to disable the `ping`command itself?

Comment: I just want that people cannot ping my server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add a firewall rule:

```
netsh advFirewall Firewall add rule name="block PING IPv4" protocol=icmpv4:8,any dir=in action=block
```

And make sure the firewall is enabled on the profile/adapter you are using.

This can be done in the Firewall GUI, too:

Open Advanced Firewall SnapIn > Inbound Rules > New Rule > Custom Rule (with "All Programs") > Protocol Type IPv4 > Set "Specific ICMP types" to "Echo Request" > Any/Any > Block.